# Using purrr to plot a mean line on a list of ggplot2 objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I am playing around with `purrr` and the methods outlines in this [post](http://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2017-03-29-make-ggplot2-purrr/)

My goal here is to use `purrr::map2` (or some variant) to apply a function (mean in this case) by a group (cyl) then create some plots that use the result of the previous application of a function in the resulting plot. Or put, another way, I want to add a vertical line for the mean on each of these plots using the `mean_list` list column all within a `dplyr` chain. Is this possible?

```
library(tidyverse)
 mt_list <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(mean_list = map2(data, cyl, ~mean(.$disp))) %>%
  mutate(plot = map2(data, cyl, ~ggplot(data = .x) +
                       geom_point(aes(y = drat, x = disp)) #+
                       #geom_vline(data = mean_list ,aes(xintercept) Unsure about this step
  ))
```

This is an example of one type of plot I'm after but this seems like a silly way to do this when the whole point is to have everything contained within a nice tibble like `mt_list`

```
mt_list$plot[[1]] +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mt_list$mean_list[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by passing `mean_list` as the second argument to `map2` rather than `cyl`, then using `xintercept = .y` in your `geom_vline`.

```
mt_list <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(mean_list = map(data, ~mean(.$disp))) %>%
  mutate(plot = map2(data, mean_list, ~ ggplot(data = .x) +
                       geom_point(aes(y = drat, x = disp)) +
                       geom_vline(xintercept = .y)
  ))
```

Note that for this particular use case, you can also avoid having to create `mean_list` at all by using `aes(xintercept = mean(disp))`:

```
mt_list <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(plot = map(data, ~ ggplot(data = .) +
                      geom_point(aes(y = drat, x = disp)) +
                      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(disp)))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am so confused by that second argument. Can you explain it at all?

Comment: @boshek Sure! But by second argument, do you mean to `map2` or to `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(disp)))`?

Comment: yeah that 2nd argument in `map2`. That would be awesome!

Comment: @boshek `map2` iterates over two lists at the same time. Items in the first list become `.x` in the formula, items in the second list become `.y`. So each nested dataset goes into `data = .x`, and each mean in `mean_list` goes into `xintercept = .y`

Comment: Ok - so what `cyl` doing in this: `mutate(mean_list = map2(data, cyl, ~mean(.$disp))) `?

Comment: @boshek It does nothing: I've fixed that to just use `map` on `data`. Thanks for pointing it out!